# NSMutableData with Expression of Type NSData Warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I've opened my project within xCode 6 GM Seed and am now getting some new warnings.  This is one warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableData *' with an expression of type 'NSData *'? How to resolve this?

```
NSMutableData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
```

Comment: Change the type of the receiver, use a data source that produces a mutable result, or ignore the warning until it bites you later.

Comment: these warnings existed before Xcode 6. you likely had them disabled in your project and they got reenabled when you updated your project settings for xcode 6.

Answer (score 2):

change to this:

```
NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
```

Comment: I don't know how this was not obvious to OP... +1